# Given acceleration relative to velocity, how to define both acceleration and velocity with respect to time

Tags: calculus

I am trying to come up with a formula for movement where the acceleration is very high at speeds near 0 and quickly falls off to a near constant as speed is gained. A maximum speed is set in the 400-500 range (units are pixels per second).

Following the logic, the equation I came up with gives an acceleration relative to speed:

$$a = 200000/s + 0.1s + 800$$

or, more exactly, to moderate the acceleration somewhat:

$$a = 200000/(s+100) + 0.1(s+100) + 800$$

The curve of acceleration vs. speed is as I want it. Different thresholds are as I want them: 2810 acceleration at 0 speed, 1820 acceleration at 100 speed, 1497 at 200 speed, etc. The problem is that I need to define speed and acceleration relative to time, and I do not know to reformulate/redefine the equation to get that.

Comment: Try using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D200000%2F%28x%2B100%29%2B0.1%28x%2B100%29%2B800) will solve this for you.  I used $x$ for your $s$ and $x'$ for your $a$.  $c_1$ is chosen to match your initial condition.  The solution gives $t$ as a function of $s$, not the other way around.  You can plot it and find approximate solutions.